# selenium wedriver program can not go on

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use webdriver to click the login button and the page has transformed correctly.but the program stop and occured the proplem "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable"
and this is the code where occured problems

```js
browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="emap-rsids-content"]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/input').send_keys(uid)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="emap-rsids-content"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/input').send_keys(pwd)
        # click to sign in

        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="emap-rsids-content"]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/button').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(3)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/article/section[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]').click()
```

this is the traceback

```js
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/14638/Desktop/auto_sign_zzu_jksb-master/auto_sign.py", line 68, in sign_in
    time.sleep(3)
  File "C:\Users\14638\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\14638\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\14638\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\14638\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)
```

the line 68 is time.sleep(3), the click works and transform to a new page,but it still occured that the button element is interctable.
I have try two methods, one is

'''
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="emap-rsids-content"]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/button').click()
'''

and another is

'''
pages=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="emap-rsids-content"]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/button')
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", pages)
'''

but still not work

Comment: I think the `Enter` actually submitted your login form and then there is a click which wouldn't work as there's no element to be clicked?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to click the element which is not completely loaded.What you have to do is wait till that happens.
First import these files

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Then add this after logging in.

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/main/article/section[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]')))
```

Then do

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/article/section[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the page_source:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="emap-rsids-content"]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/input').send_keys(uid)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="emap-rsids-content"]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/input').send_keys(pwd)
        # click to sign in

        time.sleep(5) # add some time to load the page
        browser.get(browser.current_url)
        time.sleep(1)

        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="emap-rsids-content"]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/button').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(3)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/article/section[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]').click()
```